# .Net Core Aync Method causing unexpectedly Thread Exiting with code 0

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, azure-storage

I am creating a method to return all files names from a Azure File Share, but including scan all subfolders as well. However my async method is unexpectedly been exited without any reason.

The method received the root folder (directory), this root folder has several sub folders.

However after this line :

```
                // return pageable list of directories and files.
                AsyncPageable<ShareFileItem> PageableDirectories = directoryClient.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync(directory);
```

The method unexpectedly exit from the foreach line as the PageableDirectories was empty, but it has several files.

My directory client variable is not null and is pointing to the right folder "unistad" in "unistad-files" share:

[image]

See below my code

```
       /// <summary>
        /// Returns all directories and files from the root folder.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="directory">Root folder</param>
        /// <param name="returnDirectories">True return also directories, False return files only.</param>
        /// <returns>List of directories and files.</returns>
        public async Task<List<FileResponseItem>> GetDirectoriesAndFiles(string directory, bool returnDirectories)
        {

            // Get a reference to the directory
            ShareDirectoryClient directoryClient = _shareClient.GetDirectoryClient(directory);

            // Check the client exists
            if (directoryClient != null)
            {
                // return pageable list of directories and files.
                AsyncPageable<ShareFileItem> PageableDirectories = directoryClient.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync(directory);

                List<FileResponseItem> files = new List<FileResponseItem>();

                //IAsyncEnumerator<ShareFileItem> enumerator = PageableDirectories.GetAsyncEnumerator();
                await foreach(ShareFileItem file in PageableDirectories)
                {
                    if (file.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        // If flagged to return the directories. Add the directory information to the list.
                        if (returnDirectories)
                        {
                            // Add the folder to the list to be returned.
                            files.Add(new FileResponseItem(file, ""));
                        }

                        // Recursively add the files within the sub folders.
                        string subFolder = Path.Combine(directory, file.Name);
                        List<FileResponseItem> subFolderFiles = await GetDirectoriesAndFiles(subFolder, false);

                        // Add the files found in the sub folder.
                        foreach(FileResponseItem subFolderFile in subFolderFiles)
                            files.Add(subFolderFile);
                    }                       
                    else
                        // Add the file to the list to be returned.
                        files.Add(new FileResponseItem(file,directory));
                }

                return files;

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }

    }
```

See below the instructions found in Microsoft web site:

```
async Task IterateSecretsWithAwaitForeachAsync()
{
    AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> allSecrets = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();

    await foreach (SecretProperties secret in allSecrets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"IterateSecretsWithAwaitForeachAsync: {secret.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is `directory` set to?

Comment: What is the type of the application? Is it a Console application?

Comment: Ian, you are right the directory was referenced twice, thanks for helping me on this one. The first is correct, the second one was a mistake, in the method "GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync" is actually not needed, because is a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I was referencing variable directory twice.

This line I did a mistake, to fix it I replaced directory per ""
AsyncPageable PageableDirectories = directoryClient.GetFilesAndDirectoriesAsync("");